# Without a calculator, behavior of$ f(x) = e^{(2x-x^2)}$. What does the concavity tell me?

Tags: derivatives

I am attempting to find the vertical asymptotes, horizontal asymptotes, the local minimum and maximum, and the concavity of the function $f(x) = e^{(2x-x^2)}$

In order to find the vertical asymptotes, it is wherever f(x) is undefined, which I don't believe in anywhere.  To find the horizontal asymptotes, I calculate the limit as x tends to infinity. Which is $0$.

I calculated the derivative.  That is, $\dfrac{d }{dx}e^{(2x-x^2)} = e^{(2x-x^2)}$(2-2x)

I set it to zero and solve to get the local minimum and maximum.

I take the second derivative.

What does the second derivative tell me about the concavity?  How is concavity even expressed in this graph for that matter?

Comment: If the second derivative is (strictly) negative, then the function is concave. (It may be concave if the second derivative is zero, as in $x \mapsto x^4$, but not necessarily, as in $x \mapsto x^3$). If the second derivative is (strictly) negative, then the slope of the function is decreasing, which you can usually 'see' on graphs of these sorts of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second derivative is $f''(x) = 2 e^{2 x-x^2} \left(2 x^2-4 x+1\right)$ which is zero at $(2\pm\sqrt{2})/2$.  Also, $2 e^{2 x-x^2}$ is always positive while $2 x^2-4 x+1$ is a parabola opening up and, therefore negative between the two roots while positive outside of the roots.  Therefore, $f''$ itself is negative between the two roots and positive outside of the roots.  This implies that the graph of $f(x)$ is concave down between the two and concave up outside them.  Overall, the graph of $f(x)$ looks like so:

[image]

Comment: How do you know that it is concave down between the two and concave up outside them algebraically?  That is, without the graph.

Comment: @JamesGraham See edit.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Note that 
$$
e^{2x-x^2}=e^{+1}e^{-(x-1)^2}
$$
This implies that $
e^{2x-x^2}
$ has graph similar to $e^{-x^2}$.